# Ошибка, при выполнении запроса MySql через C#

Tags: c#, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При выполнении запроса в C# возникает ошибка:
mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlexception 0x80004005 Uncnown column 'НомерТелефона' in 'field list'
Хотя в других таблицах, этой же БД, запросы выполняются без проблем.

```
string sql = $@"INSERT INTO сотрудники (ФИО , НомерТелефона , НазваниеОрганизации , АдресЭлектроннойПочты )
                            VALUES('{фИОTextBox1.Text}' , '{номерТелефонаTextBox.Text}' , '{названиеОрганизацииTextBox.Text}' , '{адресЭлектроннойПочтыTextBox.Text}')";

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
```

Название TextBox'ов и полей верное

Comment: Использование не-А символов в именах объектов без правильного квотирования всегда чревато боком (а иногда и с квотированием тоже). Ну и DDL таблицы желательно увидеть - просто чтобы убедиться, что "Название ... полей верное".

Comment: Добавил скрин, что такое не- A символы? Кириллица всм?

Comment: *Добавил скрин* А не лечим мы по фотографиям, знаете ли. Я просил DDL - это текстовый CREATE TABLE, скрипт создания таблицы. *что такое не- A символы?* А-набор - это символы, допустимые к использованию в именах файлов MS DOS, подмножество переносимого набора символов. Буквы, цифры, некоторые знаки препинания... и плюс пробел (соответственно все имеют ASCII-коды в пределах от 32 до 126). Всё остальное, включая все национальные и  мультибайтовые символы - не-А.

Comment: На скрине показываете таблицу "поставщики", а в коде вставляете в таблицу "сотрудники".